# How to find all the empty subfolders inside the folder using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of folders and each folder has subfolders.

I want to scan all main folders and subfolders to list out the empty folders.

My expected output is the list of folders and their path.

For example:

```
C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\   2020-01-16
C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\   2021-01-12
```

I tried using this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\" -Recurse | Measure-Object
```

but its giving me the total count of parent folder.

How can I get all the folders and subfolders empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
$foldersList = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\someUser\Downloads\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True}
$foldersList | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: will it recurse into the subfolder also?

Comment: Yes, it will. Give it a try once.